# Insert/ Update Procedure gives Invalid Column Name Error SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a procedure that using the merge functionality either updates or inserts records into a table. The procedure is created but when ever I try to test it I get the following errors: [image]
The columns do exist.

```
CREATE TABLE ProjectBilling
(
    projectBillID CHAR(6),
    TransAmount DECIMAL(16,9),
    TransDesc VARCHAR(255),
    TransDate DATETIME, 
    projectID CHAR(4),
    accountMgr CHAR(8),

    PRIMARY KEY (projectBillID)
)
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SP_AddUpdateProjectBill
    @projectBillID CHAR(6),
    @TransAmount DECIMAL(16,9),
    @TransDesc VARCHAR(255),
    @TransDate DATETIME,
    @projectID CHAR(4),
    @accountMgr CHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO ProjectBillingSource 
    FROM ProjectBilling

    INSERT INTO ProjectBillingSource ('projectBillID', 'TransAmount', 'TransDesc', 'TransDate', 'projectID', 'accountMgr')
    VALUES (@projectBillID, @TransAmount, @TransDesc, @TransDate, @projectID, @accountMgr)


    MERGE ProjectBilling AS T
    USING ProjectBillingSource AS S ON T.projectBillID = S.projectBillID

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET T.projectBillID = S.projectBillID,
               T.TransAmount = S.TransAmount,
               T.TransDesc = S.TransDesc,
               T.TransDate = S.TransDate,
               T.projectID = S.projectID,
               T.accountMgr = S.accountMgr

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT(projectBillID,TransAmount,TransDesc,TransDate,projectID,accountMgr) 
        VALUES(S.projectBillID, S.TransAmount, S.TransDesc, S.TransDate, S.projectID, S.accountMgr);
END
```

Comment: remove the single quote around the column name in the `insert` statement. `Insert Into ProjectBillingSource(projectBillID, TransAmount...`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because while inserting data in table 'ProjectBillingSource', you have given column in a single quote, columns name should be specified without single  quote.

```
INSERT INTO ProjectBillingSource(**'projectBillID', 'TransAmount', 'TransDesc', 'TransDate', 'projectID', 'accountMgr'**)
VALUES (@projectBillID, @TransAmount, @TransDesc, @TransDate, @projectID, @accountMgr)
```

Update the insert statement without quote like this -

```
INSERT INTO ProjectBillingSource (projectBillID, TransAmount, TransDesc, TransDate, projectID, accountMgr)
VALUES (@projectBillID, @TransAmount, @TransDesc, @TransDate, @projectID, @accountMgr)
```

Also, you should create a table only when it does not exist, like this -

```
if OBJECT_ID('ProjectBillingSource') is null
begin
    SELECT * INTO ProjectBillingSource FROM ProjectBilling
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this updated stored procedure.

```
Create  Table ProjectBilling
(
projectBillID char(6),
TransAmount decimal(16,9),
TransDesc varchar(255),
TransDate datetime, 
projectID char(4),
accountMgr char(8),

PRIMARY KEY (projectBillID)
)
go

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.PROCEDURES WHERE NAME ='SP_AddUpdateProjectBill')
BEGIN
        DROP PROCEDURE SP_AddUpdateProjectBill
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_AddUpdateProjectBill
     @projectBillID char(6),
     @TransAmount decimal(16,9),
     @TransDesc varchar(255),
     @TransDate datetime,
     @projectID char(4),
     @accountMgr char(8)

AS
BEGIN


SELECT * INTO ProjectBillingSource FROM ProjectBilling

Insert Into ProjectBillingSource('projectBillID','TransAmount','TransDesc','TransDate','projectID','accountMgr')
VALUES(@projectBillID, @TransAmount, @TransDesc, @TransDate, @projectID, @accountMgr)


MERGE ProjectBilling AS T
USING ProjectBillingSource AS S
ON T.projectBillID = S.projectBillID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET T.projectBillID = S.projectBillID,
               T.TransAmount = S.TransAmount,
               T.TransDesc = S.TransDesc,
               T.TransDate = S.TransDate,
               T.projectID = S.projectID,
               T.accountMgr = S.accountMgr

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(projectBillID,TransAmount,TransDesc,TransDate,projectID,accountMgr) Values(S.projectBillID, S.TransAmount, S.TransDesc, S.TransDate, S.projectID, S.accountMgr);
end
```

Your mistake below it's didn't work.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SP_AddUpdateProjectBill
```

Replace to above condition.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.PROCEDURES WHERE NAME ='SP_AddUpdateProjectBill')
BEGIN
        DROP PROCEDURE SP_AddUpdateProjectBill
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_AddUpdateProjectBill
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your stored procedure as below

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SP_AddUpdateProjectBill

     @projectBillID char(6),
     @TransAmount decimal(16,9),
     @TransDesc varchar(255),
     @TransDate datetime,
     @projectID char(4),
     @accountMgr char(8)

AS
BEGIN

Declare @ProjectBillingSource Table
(
     ProjectBillID char(6),
     TransAmount decimal(16,9),
     TransDesc varchar(255),
     TransDate datetime,
     ProjectID char(4),
     AccountMgr char(8)
);

--SELECT * INTO ProjectBillingSource FROM ProjectBilling

Insert Into @ProjectBillingSource([ProjectBillID],[TransAmount],[TransDesc],[TransDate],[ProjectID],[AccountMgr])
VALUES(@projectBillID, @TransAmount, @TransDesc, @TransDate, @projectID, @accountMgr)


MERGE ProjectBilling AS T
USING @ProjectBillingSource AS S
ON T.projectBillID = S.projectBillID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET T.projectBillID = S.projectBillID,
               T.TransAmount = S.TransAmount,
               T.TransDesc = S.TransDesc,
               T.TransDate = S.TransDate,
               T.projectID = S.projectID,
               T.accountMgr = S.accountMgr

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(projectBillID,TransAmount,TransDesc,TransDate,projectID,accountMgr) Values(S.projectBillID, S.TransAmount, S.TransDesc, S.TransDate, S.projectID, S.accountMgr);
end
```